# Why can't I escape the braces "]" in sed?

Tags: sed, regular-expression, quoting

**Question**: Why can't I escape the "]"?

```
$ printf "*#$@~\!&*()[]\n"
*#~\!&*()[]
$ printf "*#$@~\!&*()[]\n" | sed 's/[*#$@~!&*()\[\]]//g'
*#~\!&*()
$
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Inside `[...]`, backslash is not special. `[\[]` matches both backslash and `[`<sup>1</sup>.

If you want to include the `]` character in the set, you have to make sure it's first: `[]X]` matches `]` or `X` while `[X]]` would match `X` followed by `]` (and `[X\]]` would match `X` or `\` followed by `]`). To exclude it, it has to be right after `^`: `[^]X]` is any character but `]` or `X`.

So, in your example:

```
sed 's/[]*\#$@~!&*()[]//g'
```

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>There are some exceptions to that with GNU `sed` when the POSIX conformance mode has not been enabled (via `$POSIXLY_CORRECT` or `--posix`) which is why, for compatibility with that implementation, when you do need backslash to be included in the set, it's better to write it as `[\\]`.</sup>